# How do I use jQuery to change the style of text in a table's row when a button is pressed?

Tags: jquery, button, html-table

I have a table and I will have a dead button next to each row for people to press when they notice a link is dead. When the "Dead" button is pressed, I would like for the row to have a line across it.

Button isn't pressed:

```
<td>cupcake</td>
<td>cupcake</td>
<td>cupcake</td>
<td>cupcake</td>
<td>cupcake</td>
<td>cupcake</td>
<td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-mini" type="button" id="dead">Dead</button></td>
```

When button pressed, this happens:

```
<td style="text-decoration:line-through">cupcake</td>
<td style="text-decoration:line-through">cupcake</td>
<td style="text-decoration:line-through">cupcake</td>
<td style="text-decoration:line-through">cupcake</td>
<td style="text-decoration:line-through">cupcake</td>
<td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-mini" type="button" id="dead">Dead</button></td>
```

I tried this and it did not work:

```
$("#dead").click(function() {
<td style="text-decoration:line-through"></td>
    <td style="text-decoration:line-through"></td>
    <td style="text-decoration:line-through"></td>
    <td style="text-decoration:line-through"></td>
    <td style="text-decoration:line-through"></td>;
});
```

Comment: Create a SSCCE on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, id must be unique in a page so you cant use `'dead'` as id in your case.
You may use it as class intead and try it this way:

```
$('table').on('click','.dead',function(){
      $(this).parent().siblings().css({textDecoration: 'line-through'});
});
```

Here's a sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mx4Ur/)..

Answer (score 1):

You just need to apply the style to your td

Try the following:

```
$('#dead').click(function(){
    $('td').css({textDecoration: 'line-through'});
});
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n99pL/

Comment: Thank you. Yours worked but it crossed out everything instead of just that specific row. Nix's did what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

you're mixing javascript with HTML, which will not work, although you're on the right track. Your jquery will be something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#dead').on('click',function() {
        $(this).parent().siblings().css({'text-decoration':'line-through'});
    });
});
```

example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/faak5/

Comment: thank you! it worked but when i added another row to yours, it didnt work on that new row.

Comment: what do you mean added a new row? new row of button or new row of cupcake? It should work still if its the latter, if its the former it won't work because you have `#dead` as an id and not a class.

Comment: i added dead in the class for yours and it still didnt. it could be something im doing wrong though http://jsfiddle.net/faak5/3/

Comment: now you just need to change the $('#dead') to $('.dead'). # is an ID selector, while . is a class selector. you might want to go learn more on jquery